# В строке символов посчитать количество скобок различного вида

Tags: c, алгоритм

Задача понятная, однако возможно ли как-то посчитать не используя это длинное условие `(if(st[i] == '{' || st[i] == '}' ||st[i] == '(' || st[i] == ')' || st[i] == '[' || st[i] == ']' || st[i] == '<' || st[i] == '>'))`?

Comment: В целом, зная какие символы могут встречаться у Вас в строке, можно использовать функции, т.к., например, isalpha и брать от них отрицание.

Comment: Какие у Вас символы есть в строке?

Answer (score 7):

```
strchr("{}()[]<>",st[i]);
```

Если ну позарез нужна скорость - пусть ценой памяти - то можно сделать массив, скажем, `arr` из 248 `false`, где `true` только в местах, где интересующие скобки - и все, достаточно проверять `arr[st[i]]`...

**Update** специально для @0andriy

Кэш, который бы заметил разницу в 256 байт, ныне представляется сомнительным :) А вот разицу между обращением к байту и int'у я наблюдал. Ну, эксперимент, так эксперимент.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

vector<bool>          bVec(256,false);
vector<unsigned char> uVec(256,0);
vector<int>           iVec(256,0);

template<typename V>
int count(const V& v, const string& s)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(auto c: s)
        if (v[c]) ++counter;
    return counter;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char * sk = "[]{}()<>";
    for(const char * c = sk; *c; ++c)
    {
        bVec[*c] = true;
        uVec[*c] = 1;
        iVec[*c] = 1;
    }
    string s;
    s.reserve(100000000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
        s += ' ' + rand() % ('}' - ' ' + 1);

    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        int res = count(bVec,s);
        auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << res << " for "
            << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop-start).count()
            << "mks\n";
    }
    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        int res = count(uVec,s);
        auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << res << " for "
            << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop-start).count()
            << "mks\n";
    }
    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        int res = count(iVec,s);
        auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << res << " for "
            << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop-start).count()
            << "mks\n";
    }
}
```

Вот этот код на моей машине выдал

```
8509250 for 143204mks
8509250 for 96188mks
8509250 for 43596mks
```

Все, как я и думал.

Comment: Только лучше массив битов, а не boolean.

Comment: @0andriy Ну, если вы хотите замедлить работу программы - нет вопросов!

Comment: Думаю, что как раз наоборот (за счёт размера линейки кэша), лучше, конечно, измерить.

Comment: @0andriy Ну, раз вы не можете измерить, воспользуйтесь моим дополненным ответом...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посчитать количество скобок, можно посчитать количество вообще всех байт, а затем вывести только частоту интересных байт. К примеру, чтобы посчитать скобки в stdin:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // count chars
  uintmax_t freq[1u << CHAR_BIT] = {0};
  for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF; )
    ++freq[(unsigned char)c];

  // print brackets' frequencies
  const unsigned char bracket[] = "{}()[]<>";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof bracket; ++i)
    if (freq[bracket[i]])
      printf("%c -> %ju\n", bracket[i], freq[bracket[i]]);

  return !feof(stdin); // success on eof
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/rYFqCI):

```
$ cс *.c && ./a.out <<<'(ab)'
( -> 1
) -> 1
```

Чтобы в строке посчитать:

```
const char *st = "(ab)"; // input
for (const unsigned char *s = st; *s; ++s)
  ++freq[*s];
```

Подобный способ не стоит использовать, если `CHAR_BIT` может быть большое (16, 32, 64).