# Минимизация потребления памяти корректировкой типов

Tags: c, оптимизация, память, типы-данных

Работаю с проектом, реализующим кодирование информации. В коде имеются достаточно большие двумерные массивы. Вопрос в следующем: есть ли смысл минимизировать потребление памяти, прицельно используя специальные типы данных?
Пример 1: `int stateTable[64][6];` а там, в этой таблице, сплошь нули и единицы. Нужно ли приводить к виду `uint8_t stateTable[64][6];`? При этом придётся перелопачивать весь проект и править все типы во всех методах, где используется эта таблица.
Пример 2: `for(int i; i < N; ++i)` - а по логике работы больше итератор не может быть больше 64. Нужно ли "забирать" у него лишнюю память?
Стоят ли подобные ухищрения времени, или это незначащие мелочи?

Comment: А на этот вопрос ответ вам может дать только профилирование. Иначе вы будете пол-жизни заниматься заменой `i++` на `++i`. Меняйте только то, что создаёт вам реальные задержки.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, они помогли мне, и заниматься такой микрооптимизацией я не буду)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

64*6*4 = 1536 - полтора килобайта. Я бы даже не переживал за такие размеры. Но если эту таблицу нужно постоянно копировать туда-сюда, а там на самом деле ноли и единицы, то может и упаковать ее (используя битовые операции)

> При этом придётся перелопачивать весь проект и править все типы во всех методах, где используется эта таблица.

Для этого используют typedef. Заводят свой новый тип и его уже используют. Это позволит и посмотреть на реальное использование. Да и просто обычными ifdef можно будет легко переключать.

> for(int i; i < N; ++i)

А вот здесь все куда интереснее. Вы можете конечно написать uint8_t (и не забыть инициализировать i, а то мало чего). Но вот только это не улучшит ситуацию. Компилятор скорее всего забросит i  в регистр, где оно будет как минимум 32бита. А если использовать uint8_t, то компилятор может взять и начать делать касты (но может и не начать). Что бы не гадать, в [stdint.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h) завезли специальные типы для этого случая. Вам наверно подойдет 'uint_fast8_t'. На моей машине внутри этот тип определен так

```
typedef unsigned char uint_fast8_t;
```

(я думал, там будет unsigned int).

Но вот использовать этот тип как элемент массива я уже бы не стал - обычно все алгоритмы кодирования информации очень трепетно к размерам относятся, а здесь может от компилятора к компилятору меняться.

**Итого**.

Мое предложение - для всех  "сомневающихся случаев" заведите свой тип, объявите его в одном глобальном хедере и просто используйте. Если что то поменяется - так будет проще.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы смотрел, что важнее - скорость или память.

Битовые операции просто потребуют лишних вычислений. Байты - тоже не самые быстрые по скорости. `int` обычно быстрее (см., например, сравнение в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739040/195342)).

Поэтому я бы перед окончательным принятием решения проводил эксперименты... А для облегчения их проведения - действительно, использовал бы `typedef`, как советует @KoVadim.

Answer (score 3):

Смысл минимизировать потребление памяти, прицельно используя специальные типы данных - есть и огромный. Но есть он только в массово инстанциируемых в памяти элементах данных. Ваш пример с `int stateTable[64][6];` - пример как раз таки правильный, но такие фактические размеры массива слишком малы, чтобы говорить о необходимости экономии. (Однако это зависит и от конкретной платформы, конечно. На каких-нибудь embedded платформах с микроскопическим количеством памяти даже такая экономия может быть существенной.)

Если у вас, например, есть структура, создаваемая в миллионах/миллиардах экземпляров, то следя за упаковкой и выравниванием, пользуясь экономными типами данных и битовыми полями, вы во многих случаях сможете в разы уменьшить потребление памяти программой. (Это, кстати, именно то, для чего в языке существуют битовые поля.)

Об этом надо беспокоиться заранее и стараться избегать прямой зависимости пользовательских структур данных от явно прописанных типов данных, таких как `int`, чтобы потом не оказаться в ситуации "надо перелопачивать код всего проекта". Пользуйтесь промежуточными typedef-именами для типов и/или [принципом DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself), чтобы избежать прописывания жестко прошитых явных типов в коде программы. Непродуманное прописывание явные типов в коде - это такая же ошибка, как прописывание в коде "магических констант". Разумеется здесь не надо впадать и в другую крайность, т.е. придумывать собственные имена всем типам без исключения. Как правило, ваш опыт и ваше чутье подскажут вам, какие типы в вашей программе являются потенциально "подвижными", т.е. каким типам надо заранее дать пользовательские typedef-имена.

Что же касается "оптимизации" размеров локальных переменных, как в вашем примере с `for` - этого не просто бесполезно, а вредно. "Оптимизировать" единичные локальные переменные смысла нет. Наоборот, в таких ситуациях лучше всегда пользоваться "натуральными" типами - `int`/`unsigned int`/`size_t` для целых значений и `double` для плавающих, если у вас нет каких-то специальных веских причин использовать другой тип.